# Jquery mobile show loading spinner during page transition

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to show the JQuery mobile loading spinner during the page transition? it seems page transition always automatically close the loading widget.

What I tried to do is the following

Structure
Backbone view renders the page
Use Jquerymobile single html multi page structure
I have a viewController which I call when I start to render a page, I do the following basically

```
renderView(view) {
  $.mobile.loading( "show", { theme: "a" });
  view.$el.on("pageshow", function() {  $.mobile.loading( "hide");});
  $.mobile.changePage(view.$el, {'reverse': reverse, 'changeHash': false, 'transition': mobile_transition});
}
```

but what actually happens is when JQuery mobile start the changePage, it already automatically close the loading bar. what I want is the bar is always visible until the new view I want to transit to is totally visible

So I guess to reform the question would be is it possible to show loading spinner during the page transition animation.

Comment: An idea would be to disable it completely and then call it programmatically when the page starts and hide it when the page finished transition

Comment: what kind of architecture you're using? multi page architecture, single page? show some page transition code.

Comment: I added some more info in the question.